Unable to Get Redis Working with Django on Windows
I'm working on a Django Channels project that requires Redis as the channel_layer. However, I've discovered that Redis is not natively supported on Windows, as it's primarily designed for Linux environments. While I understand that I can use Docker or a Virtual Machine to run Redis on Windows, I'm looking for an alternative solution that allows me to use Redis without relying on Docker or any Virtual Machine.
Is there any way to set up Redis on Windows that avoids these options? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I think You can run django in WSL , Windows subsystem for Linux. inside that you can run linux commands and use redis
